# perform a function on several elements of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, indices

I have an array called `population` that contains 66 items and I want to perform the log10 on each element and display the answers as an array as well. Here is what I came up with already :

```
import math
import numpy as np

population_magnitudes = math.log10(population.item(np.arange(0,66,1)))
population_magnitudes
```

I get the following error :

```
incorrect number of indices for array
```

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand correctly, but does this answer your question ?

```
import numpy as np

population = np.arange(0,66,1)
population_magnitudes = np.log10(population)
print(population_magnitudes)
```

Output:

```
[       -inf  0.          0.30103     0.47712125  0.60205999  0.69897
  0.77815125  0.84509804  0.90308999  0.95424251  1.          1.04139269
  1.07918125  1.11394335  1.14612804  1.17609126  1.20411998  1.23044892
  1.25527251  1.2787536   1.30103     1.32221929  1.34242268  1.36172784
  1.38021124  1.39794001  1.41497335  1.43136376  1.44715803  1.462398
  1.47712125  1.49136169  1.50514998  1.51851394  1.53147892  1.54406804
  1.5563025   1.56820172  1.5797836   1.59106461  1.60205999  1.61278386
  1.62324929  1.63346846  1.64345268  1.65321251  1.66275783  1.67209786
  1.68124124  1.69019608  1.69897     1.70757018  1.71600334  1.72427587
  1.73239376  1.74036269  1.74818803  1.75587486  1.76342799  1.77085201
  1.77815125  1.78532984  1.79239169  1.79934055  1.80617997  1.81291336]
```

Comment: @Ankireddy: why did you change the range? I used the range defined in the OP (i.e. `arange(0,66,1)`)

Answer (score 1):

MAP FUNCTION

You can use the map function to apply a function to all elements in an array, it looks like this :

```
>>> import math
>>> arr = [10**x for x in range(10)]
>>> arr
[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000]
>>> ans = list(map(math.log10,arr))
>>> ans
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

LIST COMPREHENSION

You can use this method to create a list using another list iteration

```
>>> licomp = [math.log10(x) for x in arr]
>>> licomp
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

If you specifically want numpy arrays, use `np.log10` instead of `math.log10` for direct implementation. Otherwise you can follow any of the above method and then convert the obtained list to numpy array using `np.array(list_obtained)`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> nparr =  np.arange(66)
>>> nparr
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65])
>>> np.log10(nparr)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
array([      -inf, 0.        , 0.30103   , 0.47712125, 0.60205999,
       0.69897   , 0.77815125, 0.84509804, 0.90308999, 0.95424251,
       1.        , 1.04139269, 1.07918125, 1.11394335, 1.14612804,
       1.17609126, 1.20411998, 1.23044892, 1.25527251, 1.2787536 ,
       1.30103   , 1.32221929, 1.34242268, 1.36172784, 1.38021124,
       1.39794001, 1.41497335, 1.43136376, 1.44715803, 1.462398  ,
       1.47712125, 1.49136169, 1.50514998, 1.51851394, 1.53147892,
       1.54406804, 1.5563025 , 1.56820172, 1.5797836 , 1.59106461,
       1.60205999, 1.61278386, 1.62324929, 1.63346846, 1.64345268,
       1.65321251, 1.66275783, 1.67209786, 1.68124124, 1.69019608,
       1.69897   , 1.70757018, 1.71600334, 1.72427587, 1.73239376,
       1.74036269, 1.74818803, 1.75587486, 1.76342799, 1.77085201,
       1.77815125, 1.78532984, 1.79239169, 1.79934055, 1.80617997,
       1.81291336])
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
from math import log
population = [2,4,23,4]
result = [log(val, 10) for val in population]

print result 


#output [0.30102999566398114, 0.6020599913279623, 1.3617278360175928, 0.6020599913279623]
```